# Validating a custom date format in with laravel validator

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my app, the user selects date from a datepicker and the date is then displayed in the input in a format that corresponds user's locale.

When the form is submitted, I would like to validate the respective date, however, the validator does not know the date format that the date was submitted in.

My question is whether I should mutate the date into Y-m-d before it is passed to validator or is there a way I can tell the Validator the right format to validate in?

Comment: You could try with just the `date` rule, if not I would suggest to change it to `Y-m-d` before validating it. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-date

Comment: If you're using `input[type="date"]` with your datepicker, the value passed will always be `Y-m-d`.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

The easier option is to use the Laravel `date_format:format`
 rule (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-date-format). It's a built-in function in Laravel without the need for a custom rule (available in Laravel 5.0+).

You can do:

```
$rule['date'] = 'required|date_format:d/m/Y';
```

or

```
$rule['date'] = 'required|date_format:Y-m-d';
```

Answer (score 7):

[Laravel Custom Validation Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules)

You can define the multi-format date validation in your `AppServiceProvider`

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider  
{
  public function boot()
  {
    Validator::extend('new-format', function($attribute, $value, $formats) {

      foreach($formats as $format) {

        $parsed = date_parse_from_format($format, $value);

        // validation success
        if ($parsed['error_count'] === 0 && $parsed['warning_count'] === 0) {
          return true;
        }
      }

      // validation failed
      return false;
    });
  }
}
```

Now you can use custom validation rule:

`'your-date' => 'new-format:"Y-m-d H:i:s.u","Y-m-d"'`